# How to make my bot leave a voice channel if there is no one in the channel for longer than 5 minutes

Tags: discord, discord.js

So recently I have been making a Music bot for discord, but I would like to have my bot leave a channel if no one is in the voice channel for longer than 5 minutes. For now my bot disconnects by the stop command only

```
    
    if (!queue) return message.reply("There is nothing playing.").catch(console.error);
    if (!canModifyQueue(message.member)) return;

    queue.songs = [];
    queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
    queue.textChannel.send(`${message.author} ⏹ stopped the music!`).catch(console.error);
  }
};
```

Can someone help me with this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event, which emits when somebody joins or leaves a voice channel (among other things).

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

  // if nobody left the channel in question, return.
  if (oldState.channelID !==  oldState.guild.me.voice.channelID || newState.channel)
    return;

  // otherwise, check how many people are in the channel now
  if (!oldState.channel.members.size - 1) 
    setTimeout(() => { // if 1 (you), wait five minutes
      if (!oldState.channel.members.size - 1) // if there's still 1 member, 
         oldState.channel.leave(); // leave
     }, 300000); // (5 min in ms)
});
```